# Do I need re-add packages after upgrade Julia

Tags: julia

I upgrade Julia from `v1.1` to `v1.3` on win10, but the packages miss in new version.

In `v1.1`

```
$ julia_1.1
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.1.0 (2019-01-21)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

(v1.1) pkg> status
    Status `C:\Users\User\.julia\environments\v1.1\Project.toml`
  [c52e3926] Atom v0.11.3
  [4c0ca9eb] Gtk v0.18.0
  [f67ccb44] HDF5 v0.12.4
  [4138dd39] JLD v0.9.1
  [e5e0dc1b] Juno v0.7.2
  [23992714] MAT v0.6.0
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v0.26.3
  [b8865327] UnicodePlots v1.1.0
  [8f399da3] Libdl
```

But these packages does not show in `v1.3`

```
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.3.0 (2019-11-26)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

(v1.3) pkg> status
    Status `C:\Users\User\.julia\environments\v1.3\Project.toml`
  [c52e3926] Atom v0.11.3
  [67c07d97] Automa v0.8.0
  [e5e0dc1b] Juno v0.7.2
```

I tried using `update` but still not show.

And I make sure `DEPOT_PATH` has same folder (`"C:\\Users\\User\\.julia"`) and all added package in there.

```
# (in v1.3)
julia> DEPOT_PATH
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "C:\\Users\\User\\.julia"
 "D:\\app\\Julia\\1.3.0\\local\\share\\julia"
 "D:\\app\\Julia\\1.3.0\\share\\julia"
```

How do I resolve it? And in I memory, it will not happen in Linux, is it correct? 
(I use different version in docker with same volume.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each minor and major Julia version (`MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH`) uses its own environment named `vMAJOR.MINOR`. For example, for Julia `1.3.0` the environment is named `v1.3` as you can see indicated in the Pkg REPL mode in parentheses before the `pkg>`.

When you updated from 1.1.x to 1.3.0 you hence switch from environment `v1.1` to `v1.3`, which doesn't contain any packages by default. This happens on every OS.

**How to we carry over packages from, say, `v1.1` to `v1.3`?**

The environments are reflected in folders in `.julia/enironments`. The two files `Manifest.toml` and `Project.toml` in those folders represent the respective environment. You can simply create a copy of the folder `v1.1` and name it `v1.3`. Then, you fire up you Julia 1.3 REPL and, to be safe, you execute `] instantiate` which will make sure that everything is installed properly. That's it.

For more information on environments see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/Pkg/#) and [here](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/environments/).

Answer (score 1):

When you write `status` you get a path printed. You can copy the folder printed on 1.1 to the one printed in 1.3 (the folder just contains two text files).

Comment: Thanks remind `status` output in package mode. Actually, I ignored first line of output. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

No.

For upgrading between minor versions (and should also be true between major version, eg. 1.x->2.y) you don't need to redownload all packages, just create a new folder `v1.x` under `[JULIA_INSTALL_DIR]/environments` and copy there the two files `Project.toml` and `Manifest.toml` from the folder from which you want the same packages (e.g. `v1.(x-1)`).

For example, to upgrade from Julia 1.4 to Julia 1.5 in Linux, after you installed the new binaries, just type in a terminal:

```
$ cd ~/.julia/environments/
$ mkdir v1.5
$ cp v1.4/Project.toml v1.5/
$ cp v1.4/Manifest.toml v1.5/
```

When you then lunch `julia` and you will use a packege (`using xxx`) you will then notice that julia will "just" pre-recompile the package for that specific Julia version (and all its dependencies, so it may take a while) but it doesn't need to re-download the package.