# How to reuse the packages downloaded by earier version in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have many packages downloaded in my linux PC for julia (1.6.4) but after downloading the new version of julia(1.7.1) it's saying packages are not installed and asking to download them again. Is there any way to reuse those packages without downloading them again?

Comment: Do you really care about literally _downloading_ them (_from the internet_)? Or is it just the fact that you need to take _some_ action (_adding them_)?

Comment: Yeah, I care because my internet connection is slow.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226447/do-i-need-re-add-packages-after-upgrade-julia. Should still work with 1.7+

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need re-add packages after upgrade Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226447/do-i-need-re-add-packages-after-upgrade-julia) (Sorry for deleting my fast answer, but it's really a duplicate of what is written there.)

Comment: Yeah, it answered. And as you told in your answer it is not downloading the packages again. I thought I would re-download them. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, it was me who shot too quick :D glad it still helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I've re-opened this question because, while [Do I need re-add packages after upgrade Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226447/do-i-need-re-add-packages-after-upgrade-julia) touches on one part of the solution, there's a more robust option not mentioned there that may serve you well throughout package operations — [offline mode](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/api/#Pkg.offline)!  This is precisely why I asked the question I did in the comments.

Offline mode will force Pkg to re-use already-downloaded packages, even when re-adding them, even across versions. Of course the operation will fail if no versions of the package (and its dependencies) are downloaded, but it'll at least try to make the already-downloaded stuff work.

This is essential because it also allows you to create local environments without hitting the network, too.  Of course, you'll need to go back online to actually grab new packages and updates, but this may help some slow network speeds.